# Meaning of "all day long" as used by Bradley Walsh

Tags: idiom-meaning

In the TV series The Chase, presenter Bradley Walsh frequently uses the phrase 'all day long'.  In the situations when he uses it, I would expect 'perfect' or 'dead right'.   Is that a meaning for 'all day long', and if so, where is it from?   I am an English teacher and I had never heard this usage until I first watched the programme about 3 months ago.

Comment: "All day long" is a common idiom which literally means what it says -- the activity went on all day.  But it is sometimes used to mean that some concept that has been stated is considered reliably true -- it was true this morning, it's true now, and it will be true tonight.

Comment: 'Yahoo Answers' gives the answer.

Answer (score 1):

"all day long" is a very affirmative expression.
if someone who loved jelly beans were asked, "would you like a free delivery of jelly beans?", that person could easily respond, "all day long."
similarly, someone who enjoyed festivities, when asked if she might like to attend a party that night, could answer, "all day long," which, rather than showing literal accuracy, would impart a level of enthusiasm.

Comment: Hello, john. ELU prefers answers backed by supporting evidence; answers lacking such may just be opinion.

Comment: Yes, Edwin… and though Hot Licks's and john fremont's Comments make perfact sense, in 60 years I've never noticed anyone saying *all day long*, nor anything like it. the closest things I can think of are *all the life-long day* and *at the end of the day* and I don't think either has even a similar, let alone the same meaning

Comment: This answer,   as informative as it is, could be improved by a link to a source that supports its claim.